# Assign PHP session to text input using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with a hidden input:

```
$token = uniqid(rand(), TRUE); $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

<input type="hidden" name="token" value=<?=$token?>/>
```

this form submits via ajax. After saving the data to database I regenerate the token.
Now, my problem is how to update the value of the hidden input using jquery.

Comment: make an ajax call to some script that will return this token

Comment: $("#you_hiden_id").val(data);

data you get by return answer when you do ajax.

Comment: oh so it is okay then to update the input using the returned json data from the request? wouldn't that make the form less secure?

Comment: yes, as long as you verify all incoming request's token on the server side and response new token for only authorized request. anything on client side eg.form inputs could be modified via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

make ajax call using `$.post` and using  random id

```
$.post('test.php',{'arg1':math.random()},function(data)
{
   $('.hidden').val(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side (PHP code) : return the new token along with the ajax response.

On the client side (javascript code) : modify the field's value in the success callback.

Can you post some more details about your PHP code (the part that answers to the ajax call) and your javascript code (the part that sends the ajax requests, and handles the repsonse) ?

Comment: thanks but wouldn't that make my form less secure against csrf?